# Penrose proof about composition of rotations on a unit sphere

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given a rotation on the unit sphere by twice the angle $AB$, followed by another rotation by twice the angle $BC$, is equivalnet to a rotation by twice the angle $AC$. This is Penrose claim in his book "The road to reality". According to my understanding, he only proved his claim for points on the spherical triangle $AB'C'$. But why is it true for all other points on the sphere?

Comment: Surely the proof is that each of these rotations is the product of two reflections, and when we take the product of two rotations the "inner" two reflections are the same and cancel, leaving the "outer" two which gives the 3rd rotation. Doesn't that make it clear?

Comment: Penrose proof does not employ reflections. It is based only on the figure, not on anything else.

Comment: I think the pic makes it clear that the great circles (as sets) move to the right places, and as A and B' move to right places so do all points on the great circle thro AB' since distance is preserved. Ditto for the other great circles shown. Now for any other point P it will lie on a great circle with pole A, the one meeting B'C' in X say. Now the great circle thro B'C' goes to right place, so X will go to right place, and then we get great circle through AX in right place. As distance preserved P will be in right place.